# HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

В обычном классе хочу получить SessionID с помощью HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID, но получаю null. Если на самой вьюхе прописать, то все работает, а в простом классе нет. Подскажите, как решить проблему?
Касательно Сессии никаких настроек не менял, доабвил только в Global.asax.cs два метода, чтоб ID не менялся, при каждом запросе страницы.

```
 protected void Session_Start()
    { }

    protected void Session_End()
    { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Номер сессии недоступен в методах контроллера потому что сессия инициализируется позже.

Если вам нужна корзина пользователя - не надо связывать ее с сессией, сессия в современном вебе - это всегда плохо. Конкретно корзину надо связывать с профилем пользователя, там ей самое место.

Если же по какой-то причине профили использовать не получается - то в помощь [`AnonymousID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.httprequest.anonymousid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string userid;
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
  userid = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
else
  userid = "guest:" + HttpContext.Current.Request.AnonymousID;
```

Для того чтобы `AnonymousID` работал, надо в `web.config` включить [`AnonymousIdentificationModule`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.anonymousidentificationmodule.aspx):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: я думал связывать с пользовательским профилем, однако что делать с "Гостями", не всегда же юзер хочет регистрироваться, что что-то приобрести. Спасибо, буду разбираться )

Comment: @Baka при активации `AnonymousIdentificationModule` гости тоже будут иметь свои отдельные профили (я, собственно, потому и написал про этот модуль).

Comment: запускаю приложение несколько раз, тот же Id остается? Так и должно быть?) Я думал при новом запуске приложения(запроса нового юзера) Id будет меняться

Comment: @Baka куки почисти. Или режим инкогнито в браузере включи :) Да, так и должно быть - `AnonymousIdentificationModule` запоминает анонимных пользователей. Самое то для корзины.

Comment: понял, спасибо ещё раз)